# Looking for the booklet of sources from "The Purim Story"

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, purim

There is [a dramatization of the purim story called "The Purim Story"](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://mostlymusic.com/products/the-purim-story-double-cd&ved=0ahUKEwi06tXvtuXSAhVHilQKHaIuBdQQFghSMAw&usg=AFQjCNEO9aH0pKAyndKHZAzzAtpG3Xlx2A&sig2=OJImudb26MlnqzQuD6XeIw). It was originally released as a double cassette album and came with a booklet of sources i.e. which medrashim are the source for each detail in the dramatization. It is sold today as a double Cd but does not come with the booklet.

I am looking for the booklet either as a pdf scan or a to buy it.

Comment: Could you [edit] in more bibliographical information? That might help people help you find it.

Comment: I have posted your question to the publishers. Watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

The answer came back from the publishers

Mostly Music Support (Mostly Music)

Mar 21, 12:00 COT

> Sorry, we don't have the PDF of this album.